# Bootstrap 3.x: how to put multiple items in a dropdown menu line

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, drop-down-menu

Bootstrap 3.x provides for dropdown menus built from <li> <a> groups.

I want to display a list of incoming messages in a dropdown, each with some action buttons to the right.

The messages would appear in the list like this:

```
-----------------------------------------------------
| Title of message   | Delete | View | Mark as Read |
|   Preview text...  |        |      |              |
-----------------------------------------------------
| etc...                                            |
```

with the three right-hand items being clickable buttons.

I still want the entire line to highlight when hovered, like the existing 'a' tags inside a dropdown menu are highlighted.  Also, I want the user to be able to click anywhere in the Title/Preview text area to navigate to a link.

I tried using columns inside the <a> tag like this, but the columns wrap around instead of stretching to the necessary width inside the dropdown.

```
<li class="dropdown">
    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown <b class="caret"></b></a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li>
            <a href="#">
                <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="col-md-6">asdf</div>
                  <div class="col-md-2">2</div>
                  <div class="col-md-2">3</div>
                  <div class="col-md-2">4</div>
                </div>
             </a>
         </li>
    ... etc
```

Is there a better way to generate this type of list inside a dropdown?

Thanks!

Comment: If my answer was helpful to you please give it the "green check".

Answer (score 1):

For what you are trying to accomplish you might want to consider Bootstrap's built-in accordion, which uses the collapse data target. You may find yourself fighting less against the dropdown's built in styles this way, and able to customize the structure of cards better. Something like this:

```
<div id="accordion">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header" id="headingOne">
      <div class="col-md-6">
          <h5 class="mb-0">
             <button class="btn btn-link" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
             Message preview/read more text
            </button>
          </h5>
      </div>         
      <div class="col-md-2">2</div>
      <div class="col-md-2">3</div>
      <div class="col-md-2">4</div> 
    </div>
    <div id="collapseOne" class="collapse show" aria labelledby="headingOne" data-parent="#accordion">
      <div class="card-body">
           Message body here
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And that way, you can use JavaScript handlebars or whatever backend engine you're using to infinitely call more id's/collapsed areas with this template. Find more about Bootstrap accordion here: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/collapse/ and I think there's support for it in Bootstrap 3 too.